# How to specify firefox version on cypress run

Tags: javascript, docker, cypress, automation-testing

I'm trying a way to launch cypress with a specified firefox version, if i launch something like

```
cypress run --browser firefox
```

I only see version 89 running, how can I force it to launch it with different versions?

FYI, I'm launching it inside a docker container with `cypress/base:12.19.0` image

Comment: Have you tried launching by path? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Launching-by-a-path

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the path, e.g.
run -b /usr/bin/firefox_target_version

https://www.w3resource.com/cypress/command-line.php

Comment: Being in a docker container, how can i find firefox bin?

Comment: It would help if the issue being faced was shared, but here is a link that might help: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command/

Comment: this link might be also helpful https://collabnix.com/running-firefox-in-docker-container/ for the path